# White space between some divs (but not others)

Tags: css, html, whitespace

As is probably apparent, I'm quite new to html and css. I recently took them up (along with django), and have been playing with my own code and borrowing snippets from tutorials of various kinds. One of the downsides of begetting the Frankenstein you see below is that mysterious anomalies tend to materialize out of the clear blue sky. The most recent and bewildering is a tiny white space between some of my divs (the two at the top). I have searched high and low for the culprit, but have as yet had little success. If someone could take a look and offer advice, that would be amazing.

Here's my Html:

```
<head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title> BTracker </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page-container">
            <div style="background:red">
            div1
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul id="navTop">
                    <li>Hi, <strong><a href="/UserName/">UserName</a></strong></li>
                    <li><a href="/help/">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/account/settings/">Settings</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="/account/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main-nav">
                    <nav>       
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="/home/" class="homeIcon">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/news/">News</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about/">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services/">Services</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar-a">
                <div class="padding">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam gravida enim ut risus. 
                    Praesent sapien purus, ultrices a, varius ac, suscipit ut, enim. Maecenas in lectus. 
                    Donec in sapien in nibh rutrum gravida. Sed ut mauris. Fusce malesuada enim vitae lacus 
                    euismod vulputate. Nullam rhoncus mauris ac metus. Maecenas vulputate aliquam odio. 
                    Duis scelerisque justo a pede. Nam augue lorem, semper at, porta eget, placerat eget, 
                    purus. Suspendisse mattis nunc vestibulum ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="padding">
                    <h2><img src="path/to/about.gif" width="150" alt="About" /></h2>
                    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong>  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam gravida enim ut risus. 
                    Praesent sapien purus, ultrices a, varius ac, suscipit ut, enim. Maecenas in lectus. 
                    Donec in sapien in nibh rutrum gravida.</p>
                    <p>Sed ut mauris. Fusce malesuada enim vitae lacus 
                    euismod vulputate.</p>

                    <h2><img src="/path/to/contact.gif" width="250"  alt="Contact Us" /></h2>
                    <p>Phone:   (07) 867 5309<br />
                    Fax:     (07) 867 5309<br />
                    Email:   <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a><br />
                    P.O Box: 12345 Timbuck, Too</p>
                    <p><a href="#">More contact informationż/a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="altnav">
                    <a href="#">About</a> - 
                    <a href="#">Services</a> - 
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a> - 
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a> - 
                    <a href="#">Terms of Trade</a>
                </div>
                Copyright BlahBlah Webservices
                <br>
                Powered by Yours Truely
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's my css:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ STYLE.CSS ] Main Stylesheet
--------------------------------------------------------------------

[Table of Contents]

1.      Link colors

2.      MAIN STYLES
2.a     Tags defaults
2.b     Page Container
2.b     Navigations


/*------------------------------------------------------------------

1.  Link colors

------------------------------------------------------------------*/

a:link {color:white;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:blue;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:grey;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:yellow;}  /* selected link */

/*------------------------------------------------------------------

2.  MAIN STYLES
    General definitions

--------------------------------------------------------------------

/*-------------------------------
2.a Tags defaults
-------------------------------*/

html { 
    background: url("/path/to/background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding-right: 200px;
}

div {margin:0;padding:0;}

/*-------------------------------
2.b Container
-------------------------------*/

#page-container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    /* color: #979731; */
    background: black;
}

/*-------------------------------
2.c Navigation
-------------------------------*/


#navTop {
    text-align: right;
    height:32px;
    background: rgba(151, 111, 48, .4);
    background:violet;
}

    #navTop li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
        height: 8px;
        line-height:8px;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
    #navTop li.last { border: 0; }

#main-nav {
    height: 85px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav{
    /* Affects the UL element */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

    .nav li{
        /* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */

        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,from(#fefefe), color-stop(0.5,#f0f0f0), color-stop(0.51, #e6e6e6));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);

        border-right: 1px solid rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.125);

        /* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */

        box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;

        position:relative;

        float: left;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .nav li:after{

        /* This creates a pseudo element inslide each LI */ 

        content:'.';
        text-indent:-9999px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:1;
        opacity:0;

        /* Gradients! */

        background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));
        background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
        background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
        background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
        background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));

        /* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */

        box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

        /* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */

        -moz-transition:0.25s all;
        -webkit-transition:0.25s all;
        -o-transition:0.25s all;
        transition:0.25s all;
    }

    /* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */

    .nav li:first-child{
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }

    .nav li:first-child:after,
    .nav li.selected:first-child:after{
        box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

        border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    }

    .nav li:last-child{
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    }

    /* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */

    .nav li:last-child:after,
    .nav li.selected:last-child:after{
        box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;

        border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
    }

    .nav li:hover:after,
    .nav li.selected:after,
    .nav li:target:after{
        /* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
        opacity:1;
    }

    .nav:hover li.selected:after,
    .nav:hover li:target:after{
        /* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
        opacity:0;
    }

    .nav li.selected:hover:after,
    .nav li:target:hover:after{
        opacity:1 !important;
    }

    /* Styling the anchor elements */

    .nav li a{
        color: #5d5d5d;
        display: inline-block;
        font: 20px/1 Lobster,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 12px 35px 14px;
        position: relative;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        z-index:2;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    .nav a.homeIcon{
        background:url("/path/to/home.png") no-repeat center center;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        width: 16px;
    }

 #header {
    height: 130px;
    background:red;
}

#sidebar-a {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    line-height:25px;
    background:purple;
} 

    #sidebar-a .padding {
        padding: 25px;
}

#content {
    margin-right: 500px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background: orange;
}

    #content .padding {
        padding: 25px;
}

    #content h2 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-left: 150px
    }

    #content p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 66px;
    border-top:1px solid #efefef;
    padding: 13px 25px;
    line-height:20px
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    background: green;
}

    #footer #altnav {
        width: 400px;
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: can you point out in which div?

Comment: I can't see any space between any divs: http://jsfiddle.net/KN7RE/

Comment: @NullPointer The white space appears between the first, second, and third divs inside the page-container div.

Comment: @NullPointer Thanks for the comments. That's strange. Here's what I'm is showing up (I commented out the display: inline:block, but the white spaces are the same in either case). http://btrackr.no-ip.org/

Comment: @DavidPärsson Thanks for the comments. That's strange. Here's what I'm is showing up (I commented out the display: inline:block, but the white spaces are the same in either case). btrackr.no-ip.org

Answer (score 1):

The elements with attribute `inline-block` will behave as if they are inline (hence the name), and therefore any whitespace encountered will be treated as a space. For example:

```
<div></div><div></div>
```

will be rendered differently to

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

[See a live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4H8Fn/)

**You can solve this problem using HTML as follows:**

Either place all your elements on the same line, i.e.

```
<div>
    // CONTENT
</div><div>
    // CONTENT
</div><div>
    // CONTENT
</div>
```

or use HTML comments to remove the spaces

```
<div>
    //CONTENT
</div><!--
--><div>
    //CONTENT
</div>
```

**You can solve this problem using CSS as follows:**

Set the attribute `font-size: 0` on the parent, i.e.

```
parent {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0
}
parent * {
    font-size: 12px
}
```

or set the attribute `zoom: 1` on the parent, i.e.

```
parent {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Unfortunately, I must be misunderstanding something. I tried my hand at the html fix you suggested, and nothing seems to change. Oddly, commenting out the -inline-block bits doesn't seem to effect the white spaces. Here's the newly rendered page: http://btrackr.no-ip.org/

Answer (score 0):

Well hello there,

I also encountered this problem in my early days as a web dev. The problem is that there is a character (space, you have many spaces on each line - tag indentation) which is rendered. You can get rid of this problem by setting:

```
body {
    font-size: 0px;
}

* {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

and then setting the `font-size` css property for each and every element you need to display text with.

Hope it helped ;)